# Symfony 4: How load config depending on host

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Now for routing using config specified in annotations

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/Frontend
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        en: ''
        fr: '/fr'
        de: '/de'
```

For all domains language without prefix now is english. Now to set language without prefix depending on host? 
For example for a domain in Germany I want the config to be like this:

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/Frontend
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        de: ''
        fr: '/fr'
        en: '/en'
```

Comment: It's ok to see what you want to achieve but we're here more to help you to solve a problem than to give you a solution. What have you tried ?

Comment: I wonder why the prefix can't just be the locale. what is soooo horrible about that? Also I believe that this is really not intended to work "dynamically", if you use the `prefix` approach. I would just add a `{_locale}` placeholder to all routes, which is defined to be nothing or a two letter locale code. and then determine the locale by the placeholder or the domain as fallback. but it's not easy, nor is it necessary really ...

Comment: after some research: it's probably not possible to define a route param somewhere at the start of a string as optional. since you appear to be a beginner, I would suggest choosing the simple and easy solution for now and just always include the _locale in your specific route definitions (`@Route("/{_locale}/the/uri")`and possibly add another route each, without the _locale parameter (`@Route("/the/uri")`). I can tell you however, that the route without the locale parameter is inconvenient to use, when you want to generate URIs/URLs, so I'd just use the _locale-always approach